# WPF Binding Without XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a WPF app with a "Grid Window".  This window has no added XAML to it.  I create a grid (columns and rows) then place a rectangle in each one all in C#.
This allows me to make a grid where I set the 'Stroke' and show locations on the grid when I set the 'Fill'.

The entire grid is set the same, in other words, if one part of the grid is red, the whole grid is red.  Currently I set the grid by iterating through all of the rectangles and setting the 'Stroke' property.  That works fine but seems very slow compared to most of the other operations.  I would like to bind the stroke property to a variable in the C# (unless iterating is a reasonable way to handle it).

I have looked at quite a few questions here, but most want to use XAML.  My code below is based off of [Binding without XAML [WPF]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233124/binding-without-xaml-wpf).  No errors, the grid just never shows up.

```
    // put a rectangle in each square
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) // for each column
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) // for each row
        {
            // create a new rectangle with name, height, width, and starting color (transparent)
            var rect = new Rectangle()
            {
                Name = $"rec{(i + 1).ToString("00")}{(j + 1).ToString("00")}", //column 5 row 2 -> rec0502
                Height = squareSize,
                Width = squareSize,
                Fill = _ColorOff
            };

            // create the binding
            var binder = new Binding
            {
                Source = _GridColor, // Brush that is updated on color change
                Path = new PropertyPath("Stroke")
            };

            // apply the binding to the rectangle
            rect.SetBinding(Rectangle.StrokeProperty, binder);
            rect.DataContext = binder;

            // place the rectangle
            Grid.SetColumn(rect, i);         // current column
            Grid.SetRow(rect, (y - j - 1));  // same row but from the bottom (puts point 0,0 at bottom left)

            // add the rectangle to the grid
            grdBattleGrid.Children.Add(rect);
        }
    }
```

Even if iterating is fine, I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: The color name is chosen from a ComboBox on a separate window.  This updates the user settings, which in turn throws an event my "Grid Window" is subscribed to.  I convert the name to a SolidColorBrush before iterating though the rectangles.

Comment: In order to create a Binding that updates its target property you need a source property with property change notification. I guess `_GridColor` isn't. Maybe add a `GridStroke` property with change notification (e.g. implement INotifyPropertyChanged) to the class that contains the code you're showing. Then write the Binding as `var binding = new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath("GridStroke") };`. It's not necessary to set the Rectangle's DataContext.

Comment: The fill and the grid color are (generally) different colors.  If I bind it to Color property, it will be the same color, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple solution would be not to have any Binding at all. Assign `_GridColor` to the Rectangle's Stroke. Whenever the Color property of (the assumed SolidColorBrush) `_GridColor` changes, it affects all Rectangles.

```
public SolidColorBrush _GridColor { get; } = new SolidColorBrush(); 
...

var rect = new Rectangle
{
    Name = $"rec{(i + 1).ToString("00")}{(j + 1).ToString("00")}",
    Height = squareSize,
    Width = squareSize,
    Fill = _ColorOff,
    Stroke = _GridColor // here
};

Grid.SetColumn(rect, i);
Grid.SetRow(rect, (y - j - 1));
grdBattleGrid.Children.Add(rect);
```

Change the Rectangle Stroke by assigning a value to the `Color` property of the `_GridColor` Brush:

```
_GridColor.Color = Colors.Red;
```

Comment: If I update "_GridColor" will it automatically update the Stroke property?

Comment: Sure. Try e.g. `_GridColor.Color = Colors.Red;`

Comment: Updating _GridColor after it is originally set, does not change the stroke, for me. I update _GridColor when a new color name is chosen in a combobox.  I can see the debugger go through and change _GridColor, but there is no change on the GUI.

Comment: You haven't shown what _GridColor actually is, but assuming it is a SolidColorBrush, initialize it once, then only change its Color, as shown in my previous comment. If you want to assign a *new* Brush, follow what I explained in my first comment on the question, i.e. implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: This comment helped a lot.  I was using Brush and handing that SolidColorBrush.  Because of that, the ".Color" option wasn't showing up.  I really appreciate your help on this.  Updating the grid color is significantly faster than it was.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `DataContext` one time for the `Window`, not for each `Rectangle`.

Is `Binding` your own view model class from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface? [Link to MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netframework-4.8)